# Angular *ngFor to generate table 4 cells wide

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have an array in a component file that will by dynamically updated based on a database query. I need this array to be populating the contents of a table like this:

**For an array of 7 items:**

```
---------------------------------------------
| array[0] | array[1] | array[2] | array[3] |
---------------------------------------------
| array[4] | array[5] | array[6] |
----------------------------------
```

I have this method so far:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let employer of businessAdmins">
        <tr>
            <div class="card shadow m-2" style="height:25vh;width:18.75vh;border-radius:5%;overflow:hidden;">                
                <div class="ml-1"><div style="font-weight:bold">Name: </div>{{employer.data().first_name + " " + employer.data().last_name}}</div>                    
            </div>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

This works fine in producing a list of cells however I do not know how to populate them horizontally until there are 4 horizontal cells and then move on to the next line.

Comment: For an array, it's gonna pain a pain in the donkey. What you could do is use the flex-box model to achieve that. Are you open to suggestions, or do you really need an array ?

Comment: Agree with @Maryannah. It would be pretty complex to implement something like that and I don't think that's the correct way to do it. It will be more simple if you modify the structure of the data in TS.

Comment: @Arcteezy i wasn't talking about changing the data structure though.

Comment: Could do some TS processing. What do you recommend @Maryannah

Comment: By changing the data structure, I meant to do some processing in TS @Kron

Comment: @Kron I would recommend to simply follow the [flex box layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which allows you to do something very similar to what you ask for, but without the pain of the table.

Comment: @Maryannah Or he can change it into a 2D array with a set of 4 objects in each layer. That way he can do it in table itself.

Comment: @Arcteezy which isn't responsive, implies a defined screen size, and is more complex that what he has now. It's not only advantages ! But sure, it's one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple with CSS flex box. Try this code -

#### HTML

```html
<div class="table">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let employer of businessAdmins">
    <div class="card shadow">
        <div style="font-weight:bold">
          Name: {{employer.data().first_name + " " + employer.data().last_name}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;

  .card {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
  }
}
```

#### Result-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (manually) as I was not able to find the "step" in `*ngFor` so far (I've simplified your employer as simple string).
I don't like it as it's not using any advantage of the framework and we are scanning the list/array even if we don't need every element (performance issue).

```
<table>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let employer of businessAdmins; let i = index">
            <tr *ngIf="i % 4 == 0">
                    <td> {{ businessAdmins[i] }} </td>
                    <td *ngIf="businessAdmins[i+1]"> {{ businessAdmins[i+1] }} </td>
                    <td *ngIf="businessAdmins[i+2]"> {{ businessAdmins[i+2] }} </td>
                    <td *ngIf="businessAdmins[i+3]"> {{ businessAdmins[i+3] }} </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it with flex box.
[flexbox](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

```css
td {
 width: 20%;
 background-color: aqua;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}
table {
 width: 40vw;
 margin: 30px
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```